# Display 0 instead of error value in Excel cell with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

HI all , 
I have used a POI API and make excel sheet. I have calculated some value from cell with `cell.setCellFormula("...")` like calculating percentage , sum, etc.

Now if there is value like 0 in division formula then it will give me cell value like #DIV/0! . I want to replace that with `n/a` instead of #DIV/0!

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've done the formula evaluation step, you'll want to search for cells of type CELL_TYPE_ERROR or CELL_TYPE_FORMULA (with an error set). When you find one, you can call *getErrorCellValue()* to get the error type. If it's one that you want to replace (eg *FormulaError.DIV0*) then simply call cell.setCellValue("n/a") to change it to a text cell with n/a in it.